# Is there a -graphy term for an actor's television work?

Tags: single-word-requests, suffixes

Bands and solo singers have discographies, (film) actors have filmographies, and so forth.

Is there a similar term for television?

I've come across "televisiography", but the article's author compared its usage to cinematography and not filmography.

Comment: The most common orthography is [***tvography***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=tvography). But it's not *that* common, and people can usually find ways to rephrase and avoid it if they don't like it. There's the equally awkward [***bandography***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22bandography%22) for musicians who've played in a number of different bands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@[Fumble Fingers](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2637/fumblefingers) wrote in a [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/608646/is-there-a-graphy-term-for-an-actors-television-work#comment1538779_608646):

> The most common orthography is [***tvography***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=tvography&safe=active&ssui=on). But it's not that common, and people can usually find ways to rephrase and avoid it if they don't like it.

I can't find it any lexicon, but it *has* been used in contrast with *filmography* in [this book.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/From_Shtetl_to_Stardom/nl7yDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=tvography&pg=PA68&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: My housemate is a retired musician who played with a range of bands including No Dice, Spooky Tooth, Mainsqueeze, Bo Diddley, CathedraL... He's perfectly happy to say a list like that is his "bandography", because he was up on stage with all of them. But he's adamant that "session musicians" (who only contribute to studio recordings) shouldn't use that term for the bands whose albums they contributed to.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did a search and it seems to be in use, although very sparingly. For now, it'll do.